# Azure Application Insights Continuous Export Process

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am using the Application Insights APIs to get my `customEvents` data, If i enable the continuous export, the old data like 1 year ago can still accessed by the Application Insights APIs, or the APIs will show me only 90 days ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry)

> After Continuous Export copies your data to storage (where it can stay
>   for as long as you like), it's still available in Application Insights
>   for the **usual retention period.**

Which means you can only get the usual retention period of 90 days and not the old data like 1 year ago in the application insights. However, you can still get the data from your Azure storage, download it and write whatever code you need to process it.

Comment: So there isn't a way to make one API call to get those ?
that's really stupid.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, you could provide your [own feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/) to get this in future. In fact, there is one [similar feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/17454031-variable-data-retention-longer-or-shorter-than-th) which is already started by Azure Team

Comment: @Programmer Any update on my answer? If you found my answer is useful then please accept/upvote it so that it can help other community members